# Correct CSS selector for selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, xpath, css-selectors

Which css selector's correct for the following HTML code ?

```
<li class="active editing" data-index="0">
   <div class="view">
   <input class="edit"/>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get the `edit` field but my selector doesn't work:

```
find(Condition.cssClass("active editing")).find(".input").setValue(...)
```

Comment: Which of the three elements do you want to target, the LI, DIV or INPUT? and why are you having trouble with it? Currently you do not give enough information to help you.

Comment: Im interested in "edit" and as the result in input

Comment: find(Condition.cssClass("active editing")).find(".input").setValue(...) not works for me

Answer (score 4):

If your edit class is unique on the page, then you can do `.edit`  If you need to be a bit more specific, you could do more along the lines of `.active.editing input.edit`

The point is, theres no "right" answer here, there are often many different css selectors you can build that can point to the same element.  You want to find the balance between being short, concise and unique.

An example using this with webdriver could be
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".edit"));`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome: open DevTools, find you element in the DOM explorer, right-click the element and select 'Copy CSS Path'. You can test this using Selenium IDE and setting the target to "css=path_from_chrome".

Answer (score 1):

Julian brought up good points, i.e. make sure your element is unique and does not change. If it is not, then make sure you talk to your developer to add an attribute that is unique and unchanging.

You can do

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li input[class='edit']"));
```